# Incompatible type of Ant Design MenuProps when using styled-components

Tags: typescript, antd, styled-components

I'm using Ant Design with typescript and I'm trying to create a styled component wrapper of the Antd Menu component, my files are this way:

```js
// Wrapper.tsx
import { MenuProps } from "antd";

// Styles
import { StyledMenu } from "./styles";

const Menu = (props: MenuProps) => {
  return <StyledMenu {...props} />; // Typescript error when spreading props
};

export default Menu;
```

```js
// styles.ts
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Menu, MenuProps } from "antd";

export const StyledMenu = styled(Menu)<MenuProps>``;
```

But for some reason, I'm getting a typescript error when spreading wrapper props into the styled component (which doesn't make any sense because MenuProps are the same in both files), and I have no idea what could it be the problem. The typescript error message is:

```
(alias) const StyledMenu: StyledComponent<typeof Menu, DefaultTheme, MenuProps, never>
import StyledMenu

No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { items?: ItemType[] | undefined; onClick?: MenuClickEventHandler | undefined; onSelect?: SelectEventHandler | undefined; ... 285 more ...; key?: Key | ... 1 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ theme?: MenuTheme | undefined; inlineIndent?: number | undefined; _internalDisableMenuItemTitleTooltip?: boolean | undefined; items?: ItemType[] | undefined; ... 283 more ...; _internalRenderSubMenuItem?: ((originNode: ReactElement<...>, subMenuItemProps: any, stateProps: { ...; }) => ReactElement<...>) | undefine...' is not assignable to type '{ theme?: DefaultTheme | undefined; }'.
      Types of property 'theme' are incompatible.
        Type 'MenuTheme | undefined' is not assignable to type 'DefaultTheme | undefined'.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'DefaultTheme'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<typeof Menu, DefaultTheme, MenuProps, never, typeof Menu, typeof Menu>): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<typeof Menu, ... 4 more ..., typeof Menu>, string | JSXElementConstructor<...>>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ theme?: MenuTheme | undefined; inlineIndent?: number | undefined; _internalDisableMenuItemTitleTooltip?: boolean | undefined; items?: ItemType[] | undefined; ... 283 more ...; _internalRenderSubMenuItem?: ((originNode: ReactElement<...>, subMenuItemProps: any, stateProps: { ...; }) => ReactElement<...>) | undefine...' is not assignable to type '{ theme?: DefaultTheme | undefined; }'.
      Types of property 'theme' are incompatible.
        Type 'MenuTheme | undefined' is not assignable to type 'DefaultTheme | undefined'.ts(2769)
```

Does anyone know what could it be?

EDIT1: Creating a wrapper without styled-components works as expected, so its something related to styled-components